# Is it OK for SEO to create tutorial documentation pages on my website that are only shown to logged in users?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, authentication

I'm thinking to create tutorial pages (visible only if logged in) for my client. Using same CMS database. My question is, is this bad for SEO? should I tell robots to ignore these pages?

Comment: Search engines can't login so they will never see it

Comment: Presumably a not logged in user or a crawler gets redirected to the login page, correct?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller not logged users redirects to homepage, not sure about crawlers

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is definitely bad, if your intent is to be searched for the content protected by your cms login system.
In this case you don't need to tell robots to ignore the page as the spider will automatically do, they can reach your login page, but not the page that are protected from outside the login system.

Comment: I think they are asking if it will hurt the rest of the site.   You are correct that they won't be able to get that content itself to rank, but will it hurt the rest of their site?

Comment: Ah ok, so i didn't get correctly the question sorry :-), yes it can hurt the rest of the website, depends from the crawler, if he reads the robots.txt file or not and if he has an algorithm based on time and your website has too many pages. 
Luckily googlebot reads robots.txt, so you can exclude certain pages to prevent the spider to read them.